# How to change the output folder for database with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Before I work with Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Management Studio 2014 with .NET Core v2, then I updated to VS 2019, SQL Server Management Studio 2017 with .NET Core 3.

I try to create a database using EF, and for SQL Server 2014 it created at the location

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL
```

and for SQL Server 2017 I want to create it at the new location

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL
```

That's the code in Package Manager Console

```
add-migrations addtodb
update-database
```

Comment: What you say there doesn't make sense. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL` wouldn't be for a SQL Server 2014 instance, it would be for SQL Server 2017 instance. Conversely `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` is for a SQL Server 2014 instance. Your descriptions or filepaths appear to be mixed up. *But, if that is the case, then there isn't a problem here.*

Comment: You should not try to create databases for SQL Server 2017 in the `MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER` directory; that is for SQL Server 2014. `MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS` is the correct location for your **2017 express** instance.

Comment: thank you, but I can't display databases from management studio 2017 cause its locate at this path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL

Comment: The is not true.  You should be able to attach the database by selecting the folder.  The default folder may be different but using the full path you can attach any file to the SQL Server provided the mdf file is on the same machine as the SQL Server.  Normally c: but if d: is on the same machine it also works.  You cannot attach a mdf file from a network file unless the drive is on the local machine.

Comment: thanks everyone, I don't notice that I have two instances for the SQL server. when I choose the second one from the server name it goes to the right directory and I can display all my database